# Azure application gateway apply rewrite rule for path based route rule

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

The Azure application gateway is deployed with Kubernetes application gateway ingress controller. It has path based routing rule and a rewrite rule set.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: name1
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-rule-set: rewrite-rule-set-1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: host.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: service1
              port:
                number: 80
        - path: /path/*
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: service2
              port:
                number: 80
```

However,

```
appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-rule-set: rewrite-rule-set-1
```

is not working. After each deployment, the rewrite rule set has to be manually set in the portal. I want to ask, is there a way to automatically apply the rewrite rule set?

Comment: I have tested with YAML code for me it worked fine and able to create the ingress and also able to access host.com. Please help me the error what you are getting or show me how you are trying to deploy the same thing.

Comment: @Imrankhan-MT Hi. I'm trying to apply application gateway rewrite rule after the ingress is created with `appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-rule-set`. However, this is not applied. It can be seen in `Azure portal 
 -> Application Gateway -> Rewrites`

Answer (score 0):

It is solved after updating AGIC version. The AGIC is installed by Helm. Previous version is 1.4. After updating to version 1.5, the annotation works for the rewrite rules.

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to specify what version you upgraded from and to? That will make your answer more useful in the future by narrowing the range of where this issue exists.